# How to find a node with a shortest path of length equal to some number in networkx python?

Tags: python, nodes, networkx

I have a simple code to create a graph,G in networkx.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge(1,2); G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(3,1); G.add_edge(3,2)
G.add_edge(3,4); G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(4,3)
```

I want to find "which node in G is connected to the other nodes by a shortest path of length equal to the diameter of G ".

there are two of these combinations, [1,3] and [2,4], which can be found by nx.shortest_path(G, 1) and nx.shortest_path(G, 2),respectively.

Or, for example,
if I use nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=2) then I get {2: 0, 3: 1, 1: 2, 4: 2}. so the length=2 is from  node 2 to node 4, which is ok.

now, I'm trying to generalise it for all of the nodes to see if I can find the target nodes.

```
for node in G.nodes():
    target = [k for k,v in nx.shortest_path_length(G, node).items() if v == nx.diameter(G)]
    print(target)
```

and I get this odd result:

```
[3]
[1, 4]
[1, 2]
[]
```

Can anybody explain what this result means? as I'm trying to apply this method to solve a bigger problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the graph you provided:

```py
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge(1,2); G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(3,1); G.add_edge(3,2)
G.add_edge(3,4); G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(4,3)
```

The following:

```
for node in G.nodes():
    target = [k for k,v in nx.shortest_path_length(G, node).items() if v == nx.diameter(G)]
    print(target)
```

will print the target to which `node` is of distance equal to `nx.diameter(G)`

I would advise not calculating the diameter inside the `for` loop since that can turn out quite expensive.

In comparison, for a 200 node graph (`nx.barabasi_albert_graph(200, 2, seed=1)`) with the diameter calculation outside the `for` loop it takes ~74ms. The other option (with the diameter calculation inside the for loop) takes... well it's still running :´) but i'd say it will take waaay too long.

Also, instead of just the targets print the start and end nodes for readability:

```
diameter = nx.diameter(G)
for node in G.nodes():
    start_end_nodes = [(node, k) for k,v in nx.shortest_path_length(G, node).items() if v == diameter]
    print(start_end_nodes)
```

yielding:

```
[(1, 3)]          # the path from 1 to 3 has lenght 2 = nx.diameter(G)
[(2, 1), (2, 4)]  # the paths from 2 to 1 and 2 to 4 have lenght 2
[(4, 1), (4, 2)]  # the paths from 4 to 1 and 4 to 2 have lenght 2
[]                # there is no path starting at 3 that has lenght 2
```

Comment: yay, I like stackoverflow for people like you! it makes sense. I'm still not sure why it produces an empty list, [ ]  at the end for v=2. thanks!

Comment: I mean '3' should really go between '2' and '4' while nx. always puts its empty lists at the end. I wouldnt  expect to see an empty list there at all as it does not  have the length of 2.

Comment: No problem haha! ;) Basically it produces the empty list because **there is no path starting at 3** that has lenght `nx.diameter = 2`

Comment: btw, do you know how can I access the tuple (1,3) from here without an IndexError? based in its length of only 1 tuple.

Comment: You can access the tuple `(1,3)` from the list `[(1,3)]` with the usual indexing, specifically here `[(1,3)][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of the code from the reply of willcrack above (note the addition of calls to sorted):

```
diameter = nx.diameter(G)
for node in sorted(G.nodes()):
    start_end_nodes = sorted([(node, k) for k,v in nx.shortest_path_length(G, node).items()
                                        if v == diameter])
    print(node, ":", start_end_nodes)
```

will produce:

```
1 : [(1, 3)]
2 : [(2, 1), (2, 4)]
3 : []
4 : [(4, 1), (4, 2)]
```

The point is that G.nodes() returns the nodes in an arbitrary fashion based on the internal representation of the graph which likely stores the nodes in an unsorted set-like structure.